# Why can't I see my internal network in VM?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-interface

I'm running a **Lubuntu 16.04 (CLI)** virtual machine with VirtualBox. I added a second **network adapter** with the following features:

[image: Adapter features]

I then runt the following command on my terminal, to configure a DHCP server:

`VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname pomolab --ip 11.11.11.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 11.11.11.3 --upperip 11.11.11.20 --enable`

Now, if I run `ifconfig` inside the guest machine I can see only the loopback interface and the NAT interface (*Adapter 1*).

[image: The result of ifconfig]

**Why is the internal adapter not showing up?**

EDIT: here's what I get if I run `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

[image: interfaces file content]

Comment: Did you already configure the interface to autostart? You may need to add something like
`auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp`
in your /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: @JoshuaBlair thanks for your answer. I added the content of the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Do you still think I should add your line of code?

Comment: It doesn't look like your second adapter is configured. Added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the name is of your second adapter it isn't in your interfaces file. You need to add it. Just add the lines and restart networking (change the adapter name to fit your environment):

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Comment: How to get what adapter name should I use? I tried with `eth1` as you suggested earlier but `ifconfig` still shows the same output

Comment: I just tried with `enp0s8` and it works! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! FYI: `ip addr` may show you your adapters or doing a `ls /sys/class/net` may show you your adapters as well.